# How I can made a reference to a document into mediawiki page in Tuleap

Tags: mediawiki, tuleap

I would like made reference to a Tuleap document into a Tuleap-mediawiki page.
I have test doc#ID but it doesn't create a link. 
It is possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to use cross-references in Tuleap-mediawiki. The current workaround is to put links in your wiki page. E.g. 
`[https://tuleap.example.com/plugins/docman/?group_id=<PROJECT_ID>&action=show&id=<DOC_ID> my_document]`